# Getting complex infinity for solution to differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

```
DSolve[y''[x] - (2 n + 1) (3 + 2 n) y[x]/(4 x^2) + \[Beta] y[x]/
    x^(-2 n) == 0, y[x], x]
```

I am trying to solve the equation and all I am getting is `ComplexInfinity` as answer. Please help!!!

> {{y[x] -> ComplexInfinity}}

Let me give the general form of the equation that I have been working on

y''[x]- I''[x]*y[x]/I[x] + Beta^2*y[x]/(x*I[x]^2) = 0

Where I[x] is proportion to (-x)^f(n) where f(n) is a function of n

I am trying to find the function on n for which the differential equation gives a solution in terms of Bessel's function where the index of the Bessel function is a function of n

Comment: Have you tried it yet for specific values of `n` and `\[beta]`?. If I set `n` and `\[beta]` to 1, I get some Bessel function solutions, for instance. This suggests looking up the differential equation for various Bessel functions and see if you can match yours to those differential equations.

Comment: Each function must depend on all the independent variables

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

Building on my own human find-sequence-function based on a table of solutions (see below), I guessed at this simpler answer in the form desired by the OP, which turns out to solve the ODE:

```
dsol = {y ->  (* solution for n == 10 *)
    Function[{x}, (Sqrt[x] α^(1/22) BesselJ[1, (x^11 α)/11] C[1])/
      22^(1/22) + ((-1)^(1/44) 2^(21/22) Sqrt[x] α^(1/22)
        BesselY[1, (x^11 α)/11] C[2])/11^(1/22)]} /. (* replace with  n  *)
   {11 -> n + 1, 21 -> 2 (n + 1) - 1, 22 -> 2 (n + 1), 44 -> 4 (n + 1), α -> Sqrt[β]}
(*
 * the general solution:
{y -> Function[{x}, 
  (Sqrt[x] Sqrt[β]^(1/(2 (1 + n))) *
      BesselJ[1, (x^(1 + n) Sqrt[β])/(1 + n)] C[1])/(2 (1 + n))^(1/(2 (1 + n))) +
  ((-1)^(1/(4 (1 + n))) 2^((-1 + 2 (1 + n))/(2 (1 + n))) Sqrt[x] Sqrt[β]^(1/(2 (1 + n))) *
      BesselY[1, (x^(1 + n) Sqrt[β])/(1 + n)] C[2])/(1 + n)^(1/(2 (1 + n)))]}
*)
```

Check:

```
y''[x] - (2 n + 1) (3 + 2 n) y[x]/(4 x^2) + β y[x]*x^(2 n) /. dsol // FullSimplify
(*  0  *)
```

I cannot, at this point, coax this answer out of *Mathematica*, though.

*Original answer:*

Shifting `n` down `1`, solving, and shifting back yields an answer:

```
{dsol} = DSolve[{
    y''[x] - (2 n + 1) (3 + 2 n) y[x]/(4 x^2) + β y[x]*x^(2 n) == 0 /. n -> n - 1},
   y, x] /. n -> n + 1
(*
{{y -> Function[{x}, 
    2^(1 - (1 + 2 (1 + n))/(2 (1 + n))) (1 + n)^(
      1 - (1 + 2 (1 + n))/(2 (1 + n))) (x^(2 (1 + n)))^(-(1/2) + (
       1 + 2 (1 + n))/(4 (1 + n))) β^(-(1/2) + (1 + 2 (1 + n))/(
       4 (1 + n)))
       BesselJ[1, (Sqrt[x^(2 (1 + n))] Sqrt[β])/(1 + n)] C[1] + 
     C[2] MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{1/4 (-2 + 1/(1 + n)), 
         1/4 (2 + 1/(1 + n))}, {}}, -((x^(2 (1 + n)) β)/(
        4 (1 + n)^2))]]}}
*)
```

---

FWIW, somehow I figured this out from

```
Table[
 First@DSolve[
   {y''[x] - (2 n + 1) (3 + 2 n) y[x]/(4 x^2) + α^2 y[x]*x^(2 n) == 0},
   y, x],
 {n, 20}]
```

I was going to use `FindSequenceFunction` but it choked on the simple numeric coefficient `2^(-(1/(2 (1 + n)))) (1 + n)^(-(1/(2 (1 + n))))`.

Comment: Can you please tell me what that MeijerG function reduce to? Does it reduce to Bessel's function. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @SidharthaSamtani Apparently, to `-2^(-(1/(2 (1 + n)))) Sqrt[1/(1 + n)^2] π x^(1 + n) Sqrt[β] (-((x^(2 + 2 n) β)/(1 + n)^2))^(-(1/2) + 1/(4 (1 + n))) BesselY[1, Sqrt[1/(1 + n)^2] x^(1 + n) Sqrt[β]] - 2^(-(1/(2 (1 + n)))) Sqrt[1/(1 + n)^2] x^(1 + n) Sqrt[β] (-((x^(2 + 2 n) β)/(1 + n)^2))^(-(1/2) + 1/(4 (1 + n))) BesselJ[1, Sqrt[1/(1 + n)^2] x^(1 + n) Sqrt[β]] (Log[1/(1 + n)^2] + 2 Log[1/2 I Sqrt[1/(1 + n)^2] x^(1 + n) Sqrt[β]] - 2 Log[I Sqrt[1/(1 + n)^2] x^(1 + n) Sqrt[β]] - 2 (-Log[2] + Log[Sqrt[1/(1 + n)^2] x^(1 + n) Sqrt[β]]) + Log[-x^(2 (1 + n)) β])`  -- somewhat complicated...

Comment: Can you elaborate how you got the numeric coefficient where it got choked?

Comment: It just seemed "obvious" to me: If you examine `y[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 0}` where `%` is the output of the `Table`, you can see the denominators have the form `k^(1/k)`. It's not too hard to figure out that `k = 2(n + 1)` by inspection. (Is it important? To me, it suggested subtracting `1` from `n`, since some symbolic routines seem to succeed when `0` is the "origin", so to speak, and sometimes can't figure it out for themselves.)

Comment: @SidharthaSamtani My output: http://i.stack.imgur.com/u5UGx.png

Comment: Thanks for your immense help. I have found a solution by comparing my equation with modified Bessel equation given by Bowman. If you compare my equation with Bowman form you will get a nice answer. My question is whether my process is correct. Is there anything I am missing because the answer is very simple. I wonder why mathematica failed to give me the answer. Would love to know if you have something to add.

Comment: I have compared my equation with equation 3 of this page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: @SidharthaSamtani I assumed @march had something like that in mind (which comment I upvoted). I was trying to figure out why *M* doesn't recognize how to solve the Bessel-type equation. My best guess is that the `n` in the exponent, which is assumed to be a complex number, causes problems. Exponential parameters with a variable base (`x^(2n)`) are often stumbling blocks in symbolic solvers. (But also compare setting `n = I` vs. `n = -I` in your DE.) I'm not familiar enough with Bessel equations to know off-hand if that's a problem. Someone with time to investigate could probably figure it out.